# How to change the template for the ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

In ASP MVC (RC 1), how can I change the default template for ValidationSummary?

By default it ValidationSummary() shows a bullet list of errors in red. How can I change this? (i.e Have images instead of bullets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS instead of trying to change the html... for example to change the bullets to an image you can use [list-style-image](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_list-style-image.asp).

Comment: This is correct; ValidationSummary will always generate lis, so you either need to change it in CSS or use a different method.