# Change default ValidationSummary template in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to change default `Html.ValidationSummary()` template in order to make it work with twitter bootstrap. Where can I find it?

Only lead I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524935/how-to-change-the-template-for-the-validationsummary). But it does not help. I need to change the source itself since I'm using client-side validation. I've checked `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` but no html code there.

Comment: so you want to change validation summary html UI change ?

Answer (score 2):

so you either need to change it in CSS.

check this [**link**](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/example-alerts-on-error-success-and-information-with-twitter-bootstrap.html)

change line this way add in `.alert-error` and auto generated class `.validation-summary-errors` , also add related class.

```
.alert-error, .validation-summary-errors {
  color: #b94a48;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #eed3d7;
}
```

**so like this way to change css class.**

auto generated css class in `ValidationSummary`.

```
.validation-summary-errors {
    background-color: #D9FFB2;
    border:1px solid #5CBA30;
    width: 400px;
    }
span.validation-summary-errors {
    border-bottom-color: #D9FFB2;
    display:block;
    }
ul.validation-summary-errors {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-top:none;
    }
```

Comment: `.validation-summary-errors` are added at the very beginning, it just consists with empty list. If I add, for example a red border and a padding. It will show red square on every form.